# Add dynamic UILabel inside UITableview with Expend Collapse Cell with dynamic height

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

This is my response json Where I need to Add Attachments name and type dynamically (Without using storyboard), In case attachment count == 0 , attachment name/type view should not be shown

```
[{
    "Name": "Name1",
    "attachement": [{
            "imagename": "Name 1",
            "imagetype": "Png "
        },
        {
            "imagename": "Name 2",
            "imagetype": "Jpeg "
        }
    ],
    "DetailView": "This is sample detailview Example with very long information"
},
{
    "Name": "Name1",
    "attachement": [{
        "imagename": "Test Image 1",
        "imagetype": "Png "
    }],
    "DetailView": "This is sample detailview Example with very long information"
},
{
    "Name": "Name1",
    "attachement": [],
    "DetailView": "This is sample detailview Example with very long information"
}
```

]

Here is how my view looks

**Collapse case :**

```
UITableview
--Cell
---- Name Label
```

**Expend case after looping attachment to show on UILabel :**

```
 UITableview
    --Cell
    ---- Name Label
    ---- DetailView Label
      ---- imagename": "Name 1" 
      ---- imagename": "Name 2"
```

I am using [this code to Show my Expend/collapse UITableview programatically](https://medium.com/@MuralidharanKathiresan/uitableview-with-collapsible-expand-and-collapse-cells-ios-swift-8a1db381000e)

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: yes how to achieve it -> dynamic adding attachment array views in the above

Comment: OK - you probably want to put your "attainment array views" in a vertical `UIStackView` ... head over to google (or your favorite search engine) and search for `uitableviewcell uistackview` -- lots and lots of examples out there.

Comment: i already did it thanks @DonMag